# The STRANGEST error in Swift Collection View

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Im facing the strangest problem i have experienced using Swift, Im developing a game and im using a collection view cell to show the different add ons that ill have, like clothes and stuff, however, im loading the image names that every collectionviewcell is going to have within an String List, The problem appears when I want to get a check image inside the selected "thing" when i click in one cell, and if i click in other cell, the check goes to that by first deselecting all the cells, everything works fine! but when i put more than 8 items in the String list the following error appears "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" its weird because the items are shown in the collection view fine but the problem appears when i click in one of them, with more than 8 items I repeat.

This is my view controller:

```
//
//  WeaponSelectorViewController.swift
//  swiftSpriteAwesomeProject
//
//  Created by Mauri C. on 3/2/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 WANT. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class WeaponSelectorViewController: UIViewController {

    var images = [NSString]()

    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        images = ["chancla", "chancle", "chancle2", "chancle3", "chancle4", "chancle5", "chancle7"]
        images.append("chancla")
        images.append("chancla")
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return images.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as WeaponCollectionViewCell

        cell.checkImageView.hidden = true

        if(defaults.stringForKey("chancla") != nil){
            if(defaults.stringForKey("chancla")! == images[indexPath.row]){
                cell.checkImageView.hidden = false
                cell.checkImageView.image = UIImage(named: "check")
            }
        }

        cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named:images[indexPath.row])
        cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit

        return cell
    }

    // Uncomment this method to specify if the specified item should be selected
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        NSLog("\(indexPath)")

        let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as WeaponCollectionViewCell

        NSLog("\(self.images.count)")


        for var i = 0; i < self.images.count; i++ {
            var celli = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem: i, inSection: 0)) as WeaponCollectionViewCell
            celli.checkImageView.hidden = true
        }

        if(cell.checkImageView.hidden){
            cell.checkImageView.hidden = false
            cell.checkImageView.image = UIImage(named: "check")
            defaults.setObject(images[indexPath.row], forKey: "chancla")

        } else {
            cell.checkImageView.hidden = true
        }

        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: please make your question more readable. and which line cause the error

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply, I want to show a "check" image on the Selected cell of a Collection View that im populating its images names from a list of Strings called "images" as you can see, To only"check" one item, im "unckeking" every cell first on the shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath method, the problem appears in this line " var celli = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem: i, inSection: 0)) as WeaponCollectionViewCell
" inside the for loop that im using to "uncheck", its really weird, because with 8 items in the String list, it works fine! but no with more

Comment: please use backquote (``) to wrap any `code` to make it readable

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply, I want to show a "check" image on the Selected cell of a Collection View that im populating its images names from a list of Strings called "images" as you can see, To only"check" one item, im "unckeking" every cell first on the shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath method, the problem appears in this line `var celli = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem: i, inSection: 0)) as WeaponCollectionViewCell` inside the for loop that im using to "uncheck", its really weird, because with 8 items in the String list, it works fine! but no with more

Comment: It's because you're asking for cells that are not shown too, so you make it dequeue a cell for something not shown and messes things up a bit. Also, `collectionView(collectionView:shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath:)` shouldn't be used to edit things but only to determine if an item can be selectable, you have `collectionView(collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:)` for doing things in response to a selection.

Comment: I have moved all the code inside `collectionView(collectionView:shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath:)` to `collectionView(collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:)` but i still got the error I know that its something with `var celli : WeaponCollectionViewCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem: i, inSection: 0)) as WeaponCollectionViewCell` but i don't know why it works perfectly with an 8 products array :/ its really weird!? Does anyone know other way to achieve the "uncheking"??